# Basename in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

is there something like `basename` function in Flex?
I cannot find it :S

Comment: What do you expect that function to do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename I know I can easily implement this function using the functions from String class but I'm curious if such a function exists in Flex/AS 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember there isn't such function in Flex, however you can always create your own "native" version of it.

```
package {
    public function basename(path:String):String {
        var index:Number = path.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (index != -1) {
            return path.substr(index + 1);
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
trace(basename("/path/to/some/file.extension")); //file.extension
```

Answer (score 1):

download as3Corelib and look into the var _authority in the URI class